# Passing a vector of strings to a function

Tags: r

I was wondering how to get this error fixed in R (which I am new to). I have defined a function

```
> fct <- function(args = NULL) { ... }
```

However, when I call the function fct as in

```
> fct (args = c("str1", "str2", "str3"))
```

I get the following error:

```
unused argument(s) ("str2", "str3")
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does `fct` do? Does it use `args` to call some other function?

Comment: results of `traceback()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely to be something you are doing wrong inside the function.

```
fct <- function(args = NULL) { 
    paste(args, collapse=":")
 }

fct(args=c("str1","str2","str3"))
```

works for me just fine.

Comment: this might want to be just a comment, as it's likely that the question will change soon ...